# How do I make just an image clickable and not the entire div?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

How do I go about making just an image clickable and not the entire div that the clickable image is inside of? In this case, the first image, `.home`, an anchor, and the div that contains it, `.nav`, is clickable. There's a second image that doesn't have an anchor, so it's ok. How do I make just the first image inside the anchor clickable but not the div that contains them?

```css
    img.home {

      display: block;

      margin-left: auto;

      margin-right: auto;

      margin-top: 25px;

      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;

      -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;

      transform-duration: 0.8s;

    }

    img.home:hover {

      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);

      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);

      transform: rotate(360deg);

    }

    img.catfalogo {

      position: absolute;

      display: block;

      margin: 0 auto;

      top: 155px;

      left: 50%;

      z-index: 1;

      text-align: center;

      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    }

    .nav {

      position: fixed;

      height: 212px;

      width: 100%;

      background: #C9D4E7;

      z-index: 2;

      top: 0px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <p>Click to the right or left of the img.home and it will be clickable. I don't want that. I only want img.home (spinning shield) to be clickable.</p>
  <a href="informationindex.html">
    <img class="home" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/a/T2eC16ZHJHQE9nzEy9TZBQgKMjrbTw~~/s-l64.jpg" alt="home" width="67px" height="67px">
  </a>
  <img class="catfalogo" src="https://vgboxart.com/resources/logo/2250_captain-america-the-first-avenger-prev.png" alt="catfa logo" height="90px">
</div>
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6yMR.jpg) In this image, the darker area is what is currently clickable. I only want the circular image (Capt. America's shield) to be clickable. Not the entire space around it.

Thank you!

Comment: pretty tough when we don't even see the whole <div> or the code around

Comment: If you want it to link you to another page,wrap it with a link, Other wise I don't understand what you want.Can you please be more specific??

Comment: i cant seem to imagine the scenario you are describing. can you make a picture in paint and color blue the area that is clickable for you and red the area that is not clickable? - i tried running your code and only the first image is clickable, not the whole div.

Comment: @ColnsAbt Yes, I want it to link to another page. It does that, however I want only the image to link to another page, not the entire div. When I hover over the entire div, the entire div is clickable. I just want the image to be clickable. I updated the code, so hopefully that helps you understand better.

Comment: The code you present does exactly that, makes only the first image clickable. Now, based on your css it might be the whole div, so we need to see your css as well.

Comment: Why the downvote? The img is clickable and the div and second img isn't clickable as OP requested.

Comment: @LGSon I updated the question with the css.

Comment: @Anna just use `pointer-events: none` on the offending elements. See my answer.

Comment: @Banana I added an image that hopefully makes my question more clear.

Comment: @Anna updated the answer because LGSon thinks you'll get confused. Put `pointer-events:none` on the div and `poniter-events: auto;` on the img works great.

Comment: @LGSon so is my updated answer still not useful??

Comment: @LGSon Thank you for that information! However, I will only be using Firefox and Safari for this project. Thanks again!

Comment: @Anna go to http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events and you'll see that the only browser that cannot use `pointer-events` is Opera. IE11 is up to date. So about 92% of the world can get along with `pointer-events` or in your case 100% of your users.

Comment: @zer00ne Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: @LGSon Thank you so much!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The first image is clickable. The div is not clickable. Assign `pointer-events: none` to any elements' style (inline, external, etc.) and it won't be clickable. The default is `pointer-events: auto;`

```css
img.home {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
img.home:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
img.catfalogo {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 155px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 212px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #C9D4E7;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="informationindex.html">
    <img class="home" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/a/T2eC16ZHJHQE9nzEy9TZBQgKMjrbTw~~/s-l64.jpg" alt="home" width="67px" height="67px">
  </a>
  <img class="catfalogo" src="https://vgboxart.com/resources/logo/2250_captain-america-the-first-avenger-prev.png" alt="catfa logo" height="90px">
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Although the original demo was adequate to convey instructions to the OP, I have edited it because it seems that a certain member is going at great lengths to bury this question.

Comment: So what. It's to demonstrate `pointer-events` capability. If you read the answer it says >Apply `pointer-events` to any element.

Comment: What  do you mean?? Then I guess `removeEventListener` is not supposed to be used as well by your *logic*

Comment: This answer worked! Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: How did OP *add an event*? She used an anchor for the right purpose, she just doesn't want the side effects.

Comment: @Anna You're very welcome. :)

Comment: I think it is bad practice to solve this case using pointer-events when the whole problem arose from a users less knowledge of setting up css rules properly. Better to teach them how to do that if you ask me.

Comment: @LGSon how come you deleted your comments in our convo? Whatever you have stated previously you have deleted. It looks like I'm just talking to myself LoL.  So have fun censoring yourself, downvoting, and being plain rude.

Comment: *Feel free to delete your comments, I deleted mine as they no longer bring value to this question/answer, and this comment too soon, also I don't see whats rude with having an opinion about your answer.* I would show you how rude you are but you deleted it. Why would you delete a convo if it was part of a thinking process? And why bother commenting at all? This comment in itself has no basis if I didn't quote you. Stop wasting my time.